# Indy TIdHashMessageDigest5 HashStringAsHex compile time error: Undeclared identifier: 'HashStringAsHex'

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy10

Using: D7

```
uses SysUtils, StrUtils, IdHash, IdHashMessageDigest;

..

var
  idmd5: TIdHashMessageDigest5;
  h, v: string;
begin
  idmd5 := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  try
    h := idmd5.HashStringAsHex(v);
  finally
    idmd5.Free;
  end;
```

I have this code which was compiling and running fine earlier in Delphi 7, with the bundled version of Indy. After I upgraded the Indy to the latest version (v10), I am getting the compile time error:

> [Error] xxxx.pas(71): Undeclared identifier: 'HashStringAsHex'

Please help!

**Additional:**

I've solved it by changing

```
h := idmd5.HashStringAsHex(v);
```

to:

```
h := idmd5.AsHex(idmd5.HashValue(v));
```

However, the above code was in a package (custom component). In my main app, the same corrected code still throws the `undeclared identifier` when compiling.

This is really confusing now! How can the same code compile in one project, but throw a compile time error in another?!

**Update**

I've solved it. The component package was using the old Indy library. After removing that reference and updating the source to include the v10 libraries, it now works.

Comment: Read the code for TIdHashMessageDigest5.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I see that the function is moved to idHash.pas . Will it work the same if I use that class?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tried using `IdHash` class, and although `HashStringAsHex` is a public method, I still get the undeclared identifier error when compiling !

Comment: `idmd5.HashStringAsHex(v)` will work just fine in Indy 10. `idmd5.AsHex(idmd5.HashValue(v))` is for Indy 9 and will not work in Indy 10.